# How to create hierachical xml generically

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I need to be able to output hierarchical XML from SQL but I'd prefer not to have to create similar functions for each required schema.

For example, given data that looks like this:

```
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | ParentID |                           XML                            |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | NULL     | <root/>                                                  |
|  2 | 1        | <A someattr="whatever">some text</A>                     |
|  3 | 1        | <B someattr="stuff">more text <and><elements/></and></B> |
|  4 | 3        | <B1>Child of B</B1>                                      |
|  5 | 4        | <B1A/>                                                   |
|  6 | 2        | <Child_Of-A/>                                            |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

We should have an output that looks like this:

```
<root>
  <A someattr="whatever">some text<Child_Of-A /></A>
  <B someattr="stuff">more text<and><elements /></and>
    <B1>Child of B<B1A />
    </B1>
  </B>
</root>
```

(or semantically the same as)

There are plenty of posts on the internet explaining how to do this non-dynamically, but I couldn't find any generic solutions.

How can it be done without creating a new function (or set of) for each schema?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out we can do this in steps, although N.B. This is probably quite slow for large datasets (my real dataset has only 191 nodes and still takes approx. 6 seconds)

For large datasets a non-dynamic approach is probably needed.

First lets create a table-type to formalise the required input structure.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.HierachicalXMLInput AS TABLE 
(
  [ID] int,
  [ParentID] int,
  [XML] xml
)
```

The first function creates only the hieracy

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnHierachicalXMLHierachy
(   @Data dbo.HierachicalXMLInput READONLY,
    @ParentID int = NULL
)   RETURNS XML AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Out xml
    ;
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('ChangeMetoSomeUniqueNamepsace' as h)
    SELECT @Out = ( 
        SELECT [ID] AS [@ID],
               dbo.fnHierachicalXMLHierachy(@Data, [ID]) AS [*]
        FROM   @Data
        WHERE  ([ParentID]=@ParentID) Or ([ParentID] IS NULL AND @ParentID IS NULL)
        FOR XML PATH ('h:N')
    )
    RETURN @Out
END
```

This will output something like this (redundant namespace declarations omitted for clarity)

```
<h:N xmlns:h="ChangeMetoSomeUniqueNamepsace" ID="1">
  <h:N ID="2">
    <h:N ID="6" />
  </h:N>
  <h:N ID="3">
    <h:N ID="4">
      <h:N  ID="5" />
    </h:N>
  </h:N>
</h:N>
```

Then we can combine this with the original data to get the required output:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnHierachicalXML
(   @Data dbo.HierachicalXMLInput READONLY
)   RETURNS XML AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @XML xml = dbo.fnHierachicalXMLHierachy(@Data, NULL)
  DECLARE @NodeID int 
  -- we need to replace the placeholder nodes one by one.
  -- we should only replace nodes that do not have placeholder children
  -- i.e. we start deepest first
  -- find the first node to replace and get it's ID
  ; WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('ChangeMetoSomeUniqueNamepsace' as h)
  SELECT @NodeID= @XML.value('(//h:N[not(h:N)])[1]/@ID', 'int')
  DECLARE @Original xml

  WHILE @NodeID IS NOT NULL -- there is something to replace
  BEGIN
    --get the actual XML that is supposed to go where the placeholder currently is
    SELECT @Original=[XML]FROM  @Data WHERE ID=@NodeID
    -- insert the desired node after the placeholder
    SET @XML.modify('declare namespace h="ChangeMetoSomeUniqueNamepsace";  
      insert sql:variable("@Original")  after (//h:N[@ID=sql:variable("@NodeID") and not(h:N)])[1]')    
    -- if this isn't the first time around then the placeholder's placeholder children have already been replace with actual content.
    -- so insert the placeholder's content into the real node
    SET @XML.modify('
      declare namespace h="ChangeMetoSomeUniqueNamepsace";  
      insert (//h:N[@ID=sql:variable("@NodeID") and not(h:N)])[1]/*  
      as last into 
     ((//h:N[@ID=sql:variable("@NodeID") and not(h:N)])[1]/../*[. >>
       (//h:N[@ID=sql:variable("@NodeID") and not(h:N)])[1]
     ])[1]
    ')  
    -- in the above: x/../*[. >> x] is basically the same (as x::following-sibling:*)
    -- sadly it seems SQL's XML DML doesn't support axes like following-sibling, though it's not clear why this is so.
    -- Instead we use the more convoluted syntax

    -- finally, delete the placeholder
    SET @XML.modify('
      declare namespace h="ChangeMetoSomeUniqueNamepsace";  
      delete (//h:N[@ID=sql:variable("@NodeID") and not(h:N)])[1]
    ')
    -- and find the next placeholder to replace
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('ChangeMetoSomeUniqueNamepsace' as h)
    SELECT @NodeID = @XML.value('(//h:N[not(h:N)])[1]/@ID', 'int')
  END
RETURN @XML
END
```

Then we can use it like this:

```
DECLARE @dt AS dbo.HierachicalXMLInput
INSERT INTO @dt SELECT 1, NULL, '<root></root>'
INSERT INTO @dt SELECT 2, 1, '<A someattr="whatever">some text</A>'
INSERT INTO @dt SELECT 3, 1, '<B someattr="stuff">more text <and><elements/></and></B>'
INSERT INTO @dt SELECT 4, 3, '<B1>Child of B</B1>'
INSERT INTO @dt SELECT 5, 4, '<B1A/>'
INSERT INTO @dt SELECT 6, 2, '<Child_Of-A/>'

-- SELECT * FROM @dt

DECLARE @XML xml = dbo.fnHierachicalXML (@dt)
SELECT @XML
```

and get the desired output:

```
<root>
  <A someattr="whatever">some text<Child_Of-A /></A>
  <B someattr="stuff">more text <and><elements /></and><B1>Child of B<B1A /></B1></B>
</root>
```